# Decidability of real closed field with predicate

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Tarski's theorem shows that the theory of real closed fields is decidable. In section 1.3 of this presentation http://mat.msgsu.edu.tr/~aad/2012/Slides/tressl.pdf, it says that Abraham Robinson generalized this result to the theory of real closed fields in a language expanded with a predicate saying "I am algebraic". Does anyone know a reference for this result? Thanks

Comment: If you can't find the reference by looking at the references cited in the slides, then I suggest you contact the author. Please post an answer to the question here if you find one.